# how to do case insensitive search in hibernate using criteria?

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate. i want to do case insensitive search. as below.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id).ignoreCase());
```

but how to do the same in below case?

`criteria.add(Restrictions.in("name", names))`;//here **namesis a list** of names.

here how to search names in case insensitive?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to write a new expression (`CaseInsensitiveInExpression`) yourself. Use the code of `org.hibernate.criterion.InExpression` as a starting point, and transform it so that the generated SQL clause is something like

```
lower(theColumnName) in (?, ?, ?)
```

and the values passed to the query are the original values passed through `toLowerCase()` (like the `org.hibernate.criterion.ILikeExpression` does)

If you want to make database-agnostic, use `dialect.getLowercaseFunction()` to get the database function which transforms a string to lower-case, as the `ILikeExpression` does.