# case insensitive hibernate criteria on composite key

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm having a hibernate entity with composite key like the below sample.

```
class A{
B id; //this is the composite key for this class
int property1;
int property2;
int property3;
//getters and setters
}

class B{

String prop1;
String prop2;
String prop3;
}
```

In the above example **A** entity has the **B** as a **composite key**. Now I wrote the below criteria to get the **A** object by passing composite key to crieteria. Sample code is below.

```
B id=new B("Prop1Val","Prop2Val","Prop3Val");
(A) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(A.class,id)
```

***My questions are :***

1. I assume that above code makes case sensitive search. If I am
   right how can I make it to do case insensitive search?
2. Is it right way to create a criteria like below to solve the
   issue?

   ```
   Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class);
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id.prop1",id.getProp1()).ignoreCase());
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id.prop2",id.getProp2()).ignoreCase());
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id.prop3",id.getProp3()).ignoreCase());
   ```
3. Are there any simple way to configure it hbm file to use case
   insensitive by default?

Comment: Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636038/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-in-hibernate-using-criteria

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria looks fine, but your request to do a case-insensitive get by default does not make much sense. What would it do of several rows in the database have PKs differing only in case?

I would just make sure that your key properties are always in lower-case, either by throwing exceptions if upper-case values are passed to the B constructor, or by automatically transforming them to lower-case.

You could do the same using checked constraints in the database, in case some other app inserts data in the database.